# How to populate django models with form information

Tags: python, django

Right now I am having a bit of struggle trying to understand how forms work, and I am learner by example. Right now, I am trying to set up 2 models: Teacher and Student so that these models get their entries from logged users (teachers and students) but also from admin panel. So I made these 2 models and I made different views and forms for teachers so that they can create accounts by extending the AbstractUser. This model only provides me username, email, password and password confirmation. As you can see, for example,in my student model; photo, email and phone are blank=True. That is, because I want supervisor to add name, surname and student_ID only. When student creates account, he will be needed to enter these other fields as well. And also, I want that if his name, surname and student_ID don't match those from the model, he will not be able to create his account. I don't know if this approach is good or if I started bad, so I want a bit of advice. Here is what I tried:

```js
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'student_signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('index')
```

```css
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_ID = forms.CharField(max_length=14, min_length=14)
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField()

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username', 'email', 'name', 'surname', 'student_ID', 'photo',
            'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

```html
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$',
                                                             message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images')
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Try to inherit `Student` directly from `AbstractUser` and drop the User model including the two booleans.
Next point the `model` of `StudentSignUpForm.Meta` to `Student` and try again.

You don't need the booleans, the class `Student` (and/or `Teacher`) already tell you they are of that kind.

By the way, some of the fields in `Student` probably collide with the fields from `AbstractUser`. Drop them as well because you already have them.